# Django-filter and Django-tables2 Using a foreign attribute

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I've read through previous questions, and tried reading up in the docs but I've had no real luck with this.

I'm using Django-tables2 to display data of students.

One of the columns in the table (current standing) is populated using an accessor to a model manager in the student model, as follows:

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model): 
#a bunch of fields
def get_current_standing(self):
        current_standing = AcademicStanding.objects.get(year=self.enrol_term, student=self).standing
        return current_standing
```

tables.py

```
class StudentTable(tables.Table):
    current_standing = tables.Column(accessor='get_current_standing')
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ["last_name", "first_name", "campus_id", "current_standing"]
```

The table populates and displays correctly, but sorting by generates an error. I can adjust the Column as follows:

```
current_standing = tables.Column(accessor='get_current_standing', order_by='academicstanding.standing')
```

But because the relationship is 1:N I get multiple results, where (as shown by the manager in the students model), I only want the academic standing for a student for that particular year of enrolment. This method also doesn't group the entries according to the standing.

Finally, is this method of populated the table using a model manager as an accessor correct? What am I missing to enable the correct, expected functionality?

Comment: If you have more than one question you should post more than one question.  :(  For question 1, you should be able to use `.annotate()` instead of an accessor, which will fix both your sorting issue, and get rid of the inherent N+1 selects issue...  But I'm not sure enough on how to do that sort of annotation to post an answer.

Comment: @AdamBarnes thank you for that. I figured grouping them together would be better and allow a more holistic view of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Hmm...  Possibly?  Perhaps I was too hasty, as it seems like this might not even be two questions, as an annotation may solve both cases...  I don't suppose you could throw together your problem and some sample data in a repository?  I'll have a go at implementing what I'm describing, then.

Comment: @AdamBarnes if I understand correctly I would simply add .annotate(currentstanding='academicstanding__standing') to the queryset in the filter. However I now get 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression' - what am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure; this is one of those things where I need to get my fingers sticky in the code to understand.  Let me throw together a toy project now and see what I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok that was kinda fun.  Would have been faster if you'd given me a repository, but you gave plenty of information, so I was able to make my own without trouble.  :D  It's up [here](https://github.com/Asday/annotate-for-django-tables), (commit [e7f70e](https://github.com/Asday/annotate-for-django-tables/tree/e7f70ed36b763fdf9d9c74072eb99441b9324948) at time of writing).

For tidiness' sake, I did everything important in the `QuerySet`s, so take a look at [`students/managers.py`](https://github.com/Asday/annotate-for-django-tables/blob/e7f70ed36b763fdf9d9c74072eb99441b9324948/students/managers.py).

In here, you'll see the annotation that I was having trouble figuring out in the comments above.  I've translated it to something more standalone below:

```
Student.objects.annotate(current_standing=models.Subquery(
    AcademicStanding.objects \
        .filter(student=models.OuterRef('id')) \
        .filter(year__year=2018) \
        .values('standing'),
    )
)
```

Which works on the following models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, ...)

    ...


class AcademicStanding(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        'students.Student',
        related_name='academic_standings',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    standing = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    year = models.DateField()

    ...
```

The query utilises a `models.Subquery` to do, well, a subquery, using `OuterRef` to refer to the current row's `id`, meaning each `Student` will get their own `AcademicStanding` associated with them, as opposed to the first `AcademicStanding` in the set, without that filter.

With our table defined as follows, everything "just works", as the value we're interested in is now natively on the queryset.  All the performance remains, too, as this is actually calculation done within the database, instead of in Python with multiple queries.

```
class StudentTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['name', 'current_standing']
```

---

One cool thing I learned on the way through, was about `RequestConfig`.  This is something within `django-tables2` that takes the current request, and automatically does what's needed to the table it's given to match the GET parameters and such.  You can see this in action [here](https://github.com/Asday/annotate-for-django-tables/blob/e7f70ed36b763fdf9d9c74072eb99441b9324948/students/views.py#L20).  It was completely new to me.

---

For your Question 2 - I suspect that you'll find that much easier to reason about and implement with the annotation I've detailed above, but if not, please post another question for it.

(So I can get more answer points).  :P

Comment: This works! I had to adjust a few things to get it to work in the current set up. I can't seem to get the filter to work though, any suggestions on that?

Comment: I would honestly suggest a new question.  I wrote a lot in the answer above, and - in my opinion - it's very thorough.  Needing to add more to it certainly feels like a second question.  If I get to it first, I'll do my best to answer your new question; too.

Comment: That's fair, I will do so. As I posted this question the powers that be decided just to create an additional field in the student model and run a script to import the latest standing (unfortunately). So the question no longer has that much urgency. I'm going to edit my question above so that your answer completely answers the question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you also for your patience.